# How to select ndarray data in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a `ndarray` type array, for example:

```
1, 2, 0.5
2, 6, 0.9
9, 2, 0.83
```

I want to keep the rows whose 3rd elements are larger than `0.8`, and discard the other rows. It means I want this result:

```
2, 6, 0.9
9, 2, 0.83
```

How can I finish the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation of your problem:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1, 2, 0.5],[2, 6, 0.9],[9, 2, 0.83]])
result =data[data[:,2]>0.8]
```

Output:

```
[[ 2.    6.    0.9 ]
[ 9.    2.    0.83]]
```